# From Json To array javascript with exists items

Tags: javascript

I need to convert JSON object to javascript array. This my object

```
var object = 

    [
        {
            "Key": "2019",
            "value": 3
        },
    {
            "Key": "2020",
            "value": 3
        },
    {
            "Key": "2021",
            "value": 3
        }
    ]
```

i need to weel be my array like this  ['2019','2020','2021']

i try to to this

```
 var data_t = [];
                for (var i in object ) {
                    data_t.push(object );
                }
                console.log(data_t[0]);
```

But not working !!

Comment: `object.map(({Key}) => Key);`

Comment: Nothing in your question has anything to do with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` for this:

```js
var object = [
    {
      "Key": "2019",
      "value": 3
    },
    {
      "Key": "2020",
      "value": 3
    },
    {
      "Key": "2021",
      "value": 3
    }
  ];

console.log(object.map(a => a.Key));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var data_t = [];
for (var i in object ) {
    data_t.push(i.Key);
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO, please try to expand your answer with some explaination